# event getting attached to all the rows in a table (datatable) view in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, datatable

I have a view which adds a new row in table rendered with datatable plugin. I want each row to have a specific set of events attached. Here is the view:

```
var newRow=Backbone.View.extend({

        el:".datatable",


        events:{
            'click .edit':'edit',
            'click .delete':'delete'
            },


            render: function()
            {

                data=this.model.toJSON();
                this.$el.dataTable().fnAddData([data.name,data.email,data.contact_number,'<span style="cursor:pointer" class="delete">Delete</span>']);
                return this;
            },


            edit:function(){
                alert("edit");
            },

            delete:function(){
            alert("delete");
            }
        })
```

Now when i click on delete on one row it triggers the event for all the rows and i get as many alerts as there are rows. I understand what the problem is. Since i have taken el as the whole table, it goes and attaches the events in all the rows. What can be the solution to this? I need to use datatable. For simple table i should have just used el as 'tr' but really don't know how to accomplish my current desire.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is struggling with this kinda issue, please use the fnAddTr plugin from datatables like what i did:

```
var newrow=Backbone.View.extend({            

       tagName:"tr",

        events:{
            'click .edit':'edit',
            'click .delete':'delete'
            },


            render: function()
            {

            data=this.model.toJSON();

            this.$el.html('<td>'+data.name+'</td><td>'+data.email+'</td><td>'+data.contact_number+'</td><td><span class="delete">Delete</span> | <span class="edit">Edit</span></td>');
            return this;
            },


            edit:function(){
                alert("edit");
            },

            delete:function(){
            alert("delete");
            }
            });
```

And in the calling function add the tr element like this:

```
var Instance=new newRow({ model:myModel});
$('table').dataTable().fnAddTr(Instance.render().el);
```

so this line is the key `$('table').dataTable().fnAddTr(Instance.render().el);`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, was struck with exact same issue since few days and it resolved the issue quickly.